# Passing self as context in presentControllerWithNames in WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

In my presenting Interface Controller, I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)showModal {
    NSArray *namesArray = @[@"A", @"B", @"C"];
    NSArray *contextsArray = @[self, self, self];
    [self presentControllerWithNames:namesArray contexts:contextsArray];
}
```

What I would like to do, is set the passed context as a delegate property on each page of my modal paged  Interface Controller, like so:

```
#import "ModalPageInterfaceController.h"

@interface ModalPageInterfaceController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

@end

@implementation ModalPageInterfaceController

- (instancetype)initWithContext:(id)context {
    self = [super initWithContext:context];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = context;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

But what I'm finding is that the context argument is nil for all but the first page when `initWithContext:` is called, so I can not set my delegate property for those pages. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a WatchKit bug?

Comment: This functionality still exists in beta 2, so at this point I'm assuming that this is due to memory constraints and is working as Apple intends.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this was asked a while ago, but worth posting a solution.

I believe this is a WatchKit bug in Beta 3 and earlier.

The only way I found around it was to pass the argument within an array.

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"],
    contexts:@[@[self], @[@0, self], @[@0, @1, self]]];
```

It seems to just eradicate repeated contexts, so they need to be different.  My interface controller code was set up to check if the context is an array and enumerate to find the first non-NSNumber instance.

[This Apple dev forums post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1085488#1085488) explains the same solution, and a follow-up message indicates this has been fixed in Beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are holding a weak reference to your originating context. Perhaps it is being deallocated? Try:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift: Use `awakeWithContext`**

Caller:

```
self.presentControllerWithName("name", context: self)
```

Callee:

```
var delegate:AnyObject? = nil
    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        self.delegate = context
    }
```